# Postgres: Constraint with check on INSERT only

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need a constraint in Postgres which would be triggered on *INSERT* queriesonly (not on UPDATE queries).

Currently it is implemented this way :

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT check_something_const 
CHECK (check_something(id, task_id)) NOT VALID;
```

Where `check_something`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_something(UUID, UUID)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE
existed_id UUID;
BEGIN
SELECT id
INTO existed_id
FROM test WHERE ...etc. 
RETURN existed_id IS NULL
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

And currently `check_something_const` is triggered both on update and insert queries. 
What I need is this to be checked **only** when new rows are inserted, but not updated.

Comment: You will need an insert trigger

Comment: you can use after/before insert trigger. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a trigger procedure that fires on insert only.