# How to apply a CheckConstraint on creation only

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a model with a `models.DateTimeField` field and a `CheckConstraint` that prevents it from being in the past:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now

class MyModel(models.Model)
   title = models.CharField()
   mydate = models.DateTimeField()

   class Meta: 
         models.CheckConstraint(
            check=Q(mydate__gte=Now()),
            name='mydate_no_past'
        ),
```

I want the constraint to apply only when the record is first created, ideally using Django and not raw SQL (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47591936/2429989)).

In the above example, if a valid entry is created but then later the system datetime moves past the `mydate` value, when the record is updated the `CheckConstraint` fails.

How do I avoid this?

What also confuses me is if I update only other fields on the record and not `mydate` the `CheckConstraint` still fails. E.g the following will also fail if the system date is after the `mydate` value:

```
mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
mymodel.title = 'Title'
mymodel.save(update_fields=['title'])
```

Why is this?

Comment: Check it in `__init__` in Python, instead of in the database?

Comment: Thanks, yes I ideally I want this to be a db level constraint for better integrity if possible?

Comment: What confuses me is if I update only other fields on the record and not `mydate` the `CheckConstraint` still fails. Why is this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres: Constraint with check on INSERT only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588595/postgres-constraint-with-check-on-insert-only)

Comment: I don't think Django supports `Trigger` unfortunately?

Comment: You might be able to do it with raw SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will look into that; do you know why a checkconstraint would trigger on an update of another field? That doesn't seem logical to me.

Comment: A constraint is on what is in the database; if the updated row would violate the constraint then the database would be in an invalid state, regardless of which fields were updated. Normally a constraint shouldn't be something which can become false without the row changing, so strange things can happen if your constraint depends on things outside the database (like the current date).